# Flask / Automatic Database field change on True depending on the date

Tags: flask

How to make **expired**  default in False and automatic setting of the **expired** to True, depending on whether the date has passed from the field **expire_date**?

My model.py

```
class PlanPurchase(db.Model):
    plan_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('plan.plan_id'))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.user_id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    expire_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    expired = db.Column(db.Boolean)

    def __init__(self, plan_id, user_id, expire_date, total_cost=0, expired=True):
        self.plan_id = plan_id
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.expire_date = expire_date
        self.expired = expired
```

**Example.**

1. expire_date = 2020-02-02 . expired should be True.
2. expire_date = 2020-12-12 . expired should be False.

It should be automatic. Compare current date and date in **expire_date**

Comment: What kid of database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches for this.

1. If you have some kind of login system and user has to login to interact with `PlanPurchase`, then you can use `before_request` flask decorator to check for expiration and update the field. The `before_request`callback is always run before your actual endpoint request.

   ```
   @app.before_request
   def before_request_func():
    if session.get('logged_in'):
         """"
         Check for expiration 
         and update expire field accordingly.

        """

   @app.route("/login")
   def login():
   """
      Your login logic goes here.

    """
        session['logged_in'] = True
   ```
2. You can use background task like `celery` or even configure `cron` jobs to check for expiration logic every midnight and update accordingly.

*It depends upon your application architecture on which method you should use.*

**Tip:**
Seems like you are using flask_sqlalchemy. You don't need the `__init__` to pass parameters to the DB model. You can discard it.

```
class PlanPurchase(db.Model):
    plan_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('plan.plan_id'))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.user_id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    expire_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    expired = db.Column(db.Boolean)  

purhcase = PlanPurchase(plan_id=1,user_id=1,expired_date=datetime.now(),expired=False)
```

The above code works fine.